# Get validation errors in EFCore before calling SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to check if an item is deletable due to its database constraints. Is there any way to do that without calling `SaveChanges`?

My current code looks like this:

```cs
    private async Task<bool> IsDropDownDeletable(int dropDownId)
    {
        var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var scopedContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyContext>();
        await using var transaction = await scopedContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        var dropDown = new DropDown()
        {
            Id = dropDownId,
        };
        scopedContext.DropDowns.Attach(dropDown);
        scopedContext.Entry(dropDown).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        try
        {
            await scopedContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Dropdown with Id {id} can not be deleted", dropDownId);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();
            scope.Dispose();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But this throws an exception on each error (which is pretty annoying when debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database constraints are FK constraints, the only way to know without attempting the save is to ask the database or use a stored procedure to perform the deletion, returning a suitable error code or text. EF doesn't know if child rows exist unless you've tried to retrieve them with the parent item you're deleting. If it's not worth the cost of verifying the absence of child rows, then you have to handle the exception.